# SSRS count working days only

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I need some help in this my **case** is

1-two parameters date from , date to

2-number of team parameter that manually enter by user for later on use in some calculation

**rquirement**

count only working days (6days per week ) without Friday based on filtered period (date from and date to)

**Code**

```
=(COUNT(IIF(Fields!Job_Status.Value="Closed",1,Nothing))) / 
((DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Parameters!DateFrom.Value,Parameters!ToDate.Value
)) * (Parameters!Number_of_teams.Value))
```

**Note**

this code is working fine but it calculate all days

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=(DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, CDATE("2016-02-14"), CDATE("2016-02-17")) + 1)
-(DATEDIFF(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, CDATE("2016-02-14"), CDATE("2016-02-17")) * 2)
-(IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,CDATE("2016-02-14"),FirstDayOfWeek.System))="sunday",1,0)
-(IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,CDATE("2016-02-17"),FirstDayOfWeek.System))="saturday",1,0)
))
```

It will ruturn count of monday to friday between the given range in the above case it returns 3. For StartDate = 2016-02-14 and EndDate = 2016-02-21 it returns 5.

**UPDATE:** Expression to exclude friday from the count.

```
=(DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Day, Parameters!DateFrom.Value, Parameters!ToDate.Value) + 1)
-(DATEDIFF(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Parameters!DateFrom.Value, Parameters!ToDate.Value) * 1)
-(IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,Parameters!ToDate.Value,FirstDayOfWeek.System))="friday",1,0))
```

Tested with:

```
 DateFrom     ToDate     Result
2016-02-12  2016-02-19     6
2016-02-12  2016-02-18     6
2016-02-12  2016-02-15     3
```

It is very strange to me see a saturday and sunday as working days instead of friday.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: thanks for reply I will check it once i back to work

Comment: it's not working in my case working days are all week days except Friday

Comment: also note I use date from and date to as parameters shown in code that i post earlier

Comment: @MahmoudSalah, are saturday and sunday working days?

Answer (score 0):

The most sustainable solution for this kind of question, in the long term, is to create a "[date dimension](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)" aka "calendar table". That way any quirks in the classification of dates that don't conform to some neat mathematical pattern can be accommodated. If your government decides to declare date X a public holiday starting from next year, just add it to your public holidays column (attribute). If you want to group by say "work days, weekends, and public holidays" no need to reinvent the wheel, just add that classification to the calendar table and everyone has the benefit of it and you don't need to worry about inconsistency in calculation/classification. You might want the first or last working day of the month. Easy, filter by that column in the calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

Try below expression. I have tested for monthly basis to calculate working days in a month, which excludes Saturday and Sunday from calendar days:

DateDiff("d",Parameters!StartDate.Value,Parameters!EndDate.Value)) -
Round(
(((DateDiff
(DateInterval.Day,
DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,7-WeekDay(Parameters!StartDate.Value),Parameters!StartDate.Value),
DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,7-WeekDay(Parameters!EndDate.Value),DateAdd("d",-1,Parameters!EndDate.Value).AddDays(1)) + 1)/ 7)*2
)
+
iif(weekday(Parameters!EndDate.Value)=7,1,0)
+
iif(weekday(Parameters!StartDate.Value)=1,1,0)
-1
,
0
)